# Cube root using Herons method

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a cube root after Herons method.

Square root is working fine , but I am strugling with cubes root.

My formula for cubes root is: x[i+1]= (3*x[i] + N/x[i]*x[i])/4

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

double Heron(int Nummer)

{
    double x = Nummer/2;

    for(int NumAppr = 0;NumAppr<100;NumAppr++)
        {
            x = (3*x+Nummer/x*x)/4;

        }
    //double y = x/3;
    cout << "root is: " << x << endl;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    Heron(27);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you print the values as you iterate, does that match you expectations?

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea but are using the wrong formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. You're missing parentheses around `x*x`:

```
x = (3*x+Nummer/(x*x))/4;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the cube root, simply call [`std::cbrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/cbrt):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Root is: " << std::cbrt(27) << std::endl;
}

// Output: "Root is: 3"
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/436715991d03e5c6))

Comment: @CoryKramer: I'm not here to do anyone's homework; I'm here to answer questions about C++. :)

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, this site isn't to answer questions about C++, it is to answer questions posted by the OP, which in this case is to calculate the cube root specifically via Heron's method, which may or may not be how `std::cbrt` is implemented by their compiler.

Comment: @CoryKramer: The question is about getting the "cube root _after_ Heron's method", and it's certainly correct that once you've stopped fannying about with this manual calculation nonsense you'd shove in a call to `std::cbrt` and move on ;)

Comment: Pretty sure 'after' here is an English translation issue and you know it.  I like the `cbrt` answer in a smarty pants type way, but just perhaps OP was looking for help related to his code?  :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: OP should realise that this is not a helpdesk, but a repository of questions each of which must help someone else some day. Mistyping a formula hardly counts.

Comment: Stand tall and fight the wave of homework seekers then.  You'll be swimming through a whole lot of posts.  In principle though, I completely agree with you.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I do :)